# Proof by induction for a recursive function f

Tags: functions, proof-writing, recursive-algorithms, recursion

Consider the function $\operatorname{f}: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ defined recursively as follows:

1) Base case: $\operatorname{f}(0) = 0$

2) Recursive case: $\operatorname{f}(x) = \operatorname{f}(x-1)+4$, for any $x>0$

Prove that the following property holds for f by using induction on $n \in \Bbb N$:

$$2) \operatorname{f}(n+n)=f(n) + f(n)$$

This is what I have so far:

Base case : $f(0) = 0 = (2 \times 0) + (2 \times 0)$

Induction step :

Assume that $f(n + n) = f(n) + f(n)$

Show that $f((n+1)+(n+1))$ =  $f(n+1))$ + $f(n+1))$

> $$f((n+1)+(n+1)) = f((n+1) + n) + 4$$

Now I'm stuck and don't have a clue what to do next!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Just apply the recursion again:
$$\begin{align}\\
f(n+1+n+1) &=f(n+1+n)+4\\
&=f(n+n+1)+4\\
&=f(n+n)+4+4\\
&=f(n+n)+8\\
&=\{\text{induction hypothesis}\}\\
&=f(n)+f(n)+8\\
&=f(n)+4+f(n)+4
\end{align}$$

Now, what can you do with that last expression?

Comment: next line $f(n+1)+f(n+1)$? I really don't get how you even were able to take the 1 out of the first line and turn the 4 into an 8?

Comment: Yes, and you are done! And I added a couple of lines for clarity.

Comment: Ok thanks! Do you take that first four out and sort of assign it so "+1" is equal to 4? So in that last line you put the 4 back in and so it becomes n+1 again? I know this isn't worded very well...

Comment: Yes, pretty much. It's just the application of the recursive formula done forwards in the first and third rows and then backwards in the last row (that you did on your own). Think of it as "whatever the argument in $f()$ is, if I decrease it by one, I need to add $4$ to the result".